# Need to convert MySQL data block for a hyperlink using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, spaces

I have a table being displayed that converts a file uploaded location (`DocLoc`) into a hyperlink. However, because the filename has spaces in it, the hyperlink drops them off. If I display the column `docloc` it shows:

> uploading/minegem/GUI-MGEM-001 Bullet Programming.pdf

However, when I click the hyperlink I get

> uploading/minegem/GUI-MGEM-001

How can I have the hyperlink add the rest of the filename so I can open the file from the link?

```
// Printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $docname=$row['DocName'];
    $docver=$row['DocVer'];
    $doctype=$row['DocType'];
    $docloc=$row['DocLoc'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href=/uploading/$docloc>$docname</a></td>";
    echo "<td>$docver</td>";
    echo
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Sorry if this is stupid, I have done a bit of googling and reading around here and I'm struggling. I only started learning PHP, MySQL, and HTML about three days ago.

Comment: Its a good trick to learn early on to look carefully at the source code of your HTML output, if you are attuned to what is/not valid HTML then you would have perhaps spotted the reason for the error, just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the URL using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
echo '<td><a href="/uploading/'.urlencode($docloc).'">'.$docname.'</a></td>';
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the URL value for the HREF attribute. <a href="" />